# Are there ways to detect plain dm-crypt encryption and what are the countermeasures against them?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, dm-crypt

Encryption with plain dm-crypt is often positioned as encryption that cannot be recognized. But is it really so? Are there ways to prove that the data is encrypted with plain dm-crypt? How to bypass these methods?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, with LUKS you could also claim that there is no encrypted data. Presence of a header is an indicator but no proof that the rest of the disk is encrypted. It could also be just random data.

You can prove it is encrypted by decryption with the right key.

TRIM can give away that encryption is used (so the solution would be not to enable it):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD)

https://asalor.blogspot.com/2011/08/trim-dm-crypt-problems.html

Answer (score 0):

Terminology can get tricky. *High Entropy Data* such as **encryption** or **random** data is easily recognized via a number of common tests such as:

- Chi Square Distribution
- Arithmetic Mean
- Monte Carlo Pi
- Serial Correlation
- Others

Of course this doesn't necessarily differentiate ***Encryption*** from ***Random*** mathematically but not too many people keep large blocks of random data. It's not proof, but it's a strong indicator.

Note that *Compression* is generally easy to differentiate as it has much lower entropy.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there is no way to detect the existence of dm-crypt on a block device in most configurations. The only way to prove that it is encrypted is to supply the information required to decrypt it, assuming the plaintext under it is itself not indistinguishable from random.

The dm-crypt system does not provide any ciphers or modes of operation on its own. It simply *uses* existing supported algorithms. In theory, you could use an algorithm which could be distinguished from random data in some manner, but a typical device encrypted with AES-XTS will appear random.